Covariant derivative $V[\cos\theta]$.
I proved that if $E_1,E_2,E_3$ is a frame field and $W=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3f_iE_i$, we have the covariant derivative formula $$\nabla_VW=\sum_{j=1}^3\left(V[f_j]+\sum_{i=1}^3f_i\omega_{ij}(V)\right)E_j.$$
Using this useful result, if $E_1,E_2,E_3$ is the cylindrical frame field and $V$ is a vector field such that $V[r]=r,~V[\theta]=1$, then I need to compute $\nabla_V(r\cos\theta~E_1+r\sin\theta~E_3)$. In this case, $f_1=r\cos\theta$, $f_2=0$ and $f_3=r\sin\theta$. I know how to compute the connection forms of this frame field, my doubt is when i have to compute $V[f_j]$. Of course $V[f_2]=0$. Now,
$$V[f_1]=V[rcos\theta]=rV[\cos\theta]+\cos\theta V[r].$$
Intuition tells me that $V[\cos\theta]=-\sin\theta V[\theta]$, however I don't fully understand why this would work. Given this context, how do I know if $V$ is expressed in terms of $E_1,E_2,E_3$ or in terms of the natural frame field (cannonical one in $\mathbb{R}^3$)? I couldn't find a clear state about this "chain rule". I'm studying using Elementary Differential Geometry - Barrett O'Neill.

Directional derivatives certainly obey the chain rule.

I see. If $V$ is a vector field, $V[f]$ for a function $f$ can be computed setting $V=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 g_iE_i$, and then using linearity of directional derivative. $V[f]=\sum_{i=1}^3g_iE_i[f].$ $E_i$ can be written in terms of cannonical basis. But in this case I don't see what are those $g_i$ functions (scalars when we work with vector fields).

$d(\cos\theta)=-\sin\theta~d\theta$, I think evaluating that at $V$ gives me the result I want, since $V[f]=df(V)$.

Yes, so if $f=g\circ h$, then $df_p(V) = dg_{h(p)}(dh_p(V))$. There is your chain rule.

Computing it through the differential was important, since  I'm familiar with that chain rule, thanks.
